# Why am I getting duplicate symbol linker errors when building in CMake on Windows?

Tags: windows, build, cmake

I have a CMake setup to link together 4 static libraries and 1 shared one into a top level shared library (Let's call it Top.dll).  This will work fine except for one thing.  I have a module definition file that expresses which symbols should be public.  Top.dll builds and so far so good.

Now when I try to link an executable with Top.dll via CMake I get linker errors for every public symbol claiming it is defined in two places (Top.dll and the static library in which it was actually defined) even though Top.dll contains no original definitions of its own.  If I remove the static library then as expected I get unresolved symbol errors.  If I remove the module definition file, I get the same.  It seems like it is either there zero times or twice.  Is there some setting I am missing here?  I don't think I'm using CMake in a non-basic way...

**UPDATE** An explanation via CMake

```
# setup the lib
add_subdirectory(vendor/A) #shared library
add_subdirectory(vendor/B) #static library
add_subdirectory(vendor/C) #static library
add_library(Top SHARED ${ALL_SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Top A B C)
set_target_properties(Top PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS
          "/def:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/definitions.def") #contains symbols from B

add_subdirectory(C/Tests)

# CMakeLists.txt from C/Tests

add_executable(Tests ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Tests Top)
```

The above is simplified, but I will get errors like the following at the point that the C/tests project is compiled:

```
B.lib(xxx.obj) : error LNK2005: _ABC already defined in Top.lib(Top.dll)
```

If I remove B.lib from the `target_link_libraries` call, then as expected I get unresolved symbols.  If I remove the `/def` line, same result.

Comment: Some code (`CMakeLists.txt`) would express your problem better.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did my best to post a simplified version of the CMakeLists.txt files I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to get around this by setting the `target_link_libraries` of B and C to private.  This may or may not be the correct solution and I will wait for other answers.  If I don't do this it appears that the dependency is carried up to the final executable (So it links to both Top.dll and B.lib, etc).